# VBA to disconnect slicers from pivot tables, change source of pivot table, reconnect back slicers

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a VBA code which would allow me to store information about each slicers connection to PivotTables, then it would disconnect all slicers and change pivot tables source and then reconnect slicers again from information stored previous. I need these code as I can't update pivot tables source as there a lot of them connected to multiple slicers. So to unfilter all slicers manually and then reconnect them is quite time consuming task.
Here is the code which I've found and slightly modified but it gives me error. The error is probably connected with vitem.Caption and an error message is "Object doesn't support this property or method". The code is below. It might have other mistakes, so I would appreciate if you could help me modify it in order the code could work properly

```
Sub Change_Pivot_Source()

   Dim PT                          As PivotTable
   Dim ptMain                      As PivotTable
   Dim ws                          As Worksheet
   Dim oDic                        As Object
   Dim oPivots                     As Object
   Dim i                           As Long
   Dim lIndex                      As Long
   Dim Max                         As Long
   Dim vPivots
   Dim vSlicers                    As Variant
   Dim vItem
  
   Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   ' disconnect slicers
   For Each vItem In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches
      With ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_" & vItem.Caption).PivotTables
         If .Count > 0 Then
            Set oPivots = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
               oPivots.Add .Item(i).Name, .Item(i)
               .RemovePivotTable .Item(i)
            Next i
            oDic.Add vItem.Caption, oPivots
         End If
      End With
   Next vItem

   ' update pivottables
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each PT In ws.PivotTables
         If lIndex = 0 Then
            PT.ChangePivotCache _
                  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                                    SourceData:="Info[[Promo number]:[cost actual_new]]")
            Set ptMain = PT
            lIndex = 1
         Else
            PT.CacheIndex = ptMain.CacheIndex
         End If
      Next PT
   Next ws

   ' reconnect slicers
   For Each vItem In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches
      If oDic.Exists(vItem.Caption) Then
         Set oPivots = oDic(vItem.Caption)
         vPivots = oPivots.Items
         For i = LBound(vPivots) To UBound(vPivots)
            ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(vItem.Caption).PivotTables.AddPivotTable vPivots(i)
         Next i
      End If
   Next vItem

   Set oDic = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide an example workbook with the data loaded so it is faster for the community to try to see the error? It may be harder if we are not using the same data, lablels and items within.

Comment: Unfotrunately, I cannot provide workbook as each worksheet containts company's info

Comment: In my experience this sounds like an X-Y problem. Depending on why you are doing this, in future make sure the source is an actual Excel table as updating source is safer.  Is it really necessary to change the source rather than point at a table you update? Or use a query as source (output as table).

Answer (score 0):

I love this code snippet, because I was exactly looking for this solution. I know the question is quite old, but the solution of your problem is quite simple. Change all vItem.Caption to vItem.Name.